# iPhone Audio Queue, hardware decoding

Tags: iphone

I am writing an iPhone application that downloads audio files from the internet and can play them while downloading (and play white noise if network buffer is empty), so, I think, I can't use just an AVAudioPlayer and should fill audio buffer myself. Files are in MP3's and they should be hardware decoded. My first try was AudioUnit with:

```
AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat;
bzero(&audioFormat, sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription));
audioFormat.mSampleRate = 44100;
audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 2;
audioFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEGLayer3;
audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1152;
```

and then filling buffer with MP3 packets, but this is not working as Remote IO does not work with compressed streams, so I decided to dive into Audio Queue:

```
static void HandleOutputBuffer (
    void                *aqData,
    AudioQueueRef       inAQ,
    AudioQueueBufferRef inBuffer
) {
    AQPlayerState *pAqData = (AQPlayerState *) aqData;        // 1
    if (pAqData->mIsRunning == 0) return;                     // 2
    UInt32 numBytesReadFromFile;                              // 3
    UInt32 numPackets = pAqData->mNumPacketsToRead;           // 4
    AudioFileReadPackets (
        pAqData->mAudioFile,
        false,
        &numBytesReadFromFile,
        pAqData->mPacketDescs,
        pAqData->mCurrentPacket,
        &numPackets,
        inBuffer->mAudioData
    );
    if (numPackets > 0) {                                     // 5
        inBuffer->mAudioDataByteSize = numBytesReadFromFile;  // 6
        AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer (
            pAqData->mQueue,
            inBuffer,
            (pAqData->mPacketDescs ? numPackets : 0),
            pAqData->mPacketDescs
        );
        pAqData->mCurrentPacket += numPackets;                // 7
    } else {
        AudioQueueStop (
            pAqData->mQueue,
            false
        );
        pAqData->mIsRunning = false;
    }
}
```

The question is: will `pAqData->mAudioFile` be hardware decoded this way? And another question is: how can I feed mp3 data stored in NSData to AudioQueueEnqueueBuffer?

Comment: Did you find you anwser?

Comment: No, I did't find the exact answer, however, my experiments show that battery lifetime doesn't differ between my audio player with code above and standard Music application.